# Integral of (generalized) inverse functions with a twist

Tags: integration, inverse-function, monotone-functions

Consider a weakly increasing function $f : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ and define its generalized inverse (since an inverse does not necessariliy exist unless it increases strictly) as
$$ f^{-1}(t):= \begin{cases}
  1  & \text{if } f(1) <t,\\
  \inf\{s \in [0,1] \mid f(s) \leq  t\}& \text{otherwise}.
 \end{cases}$$

Note that, [similar to the result on the integral of the inverse of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions), we have

$$\int_0^1 f(x) dx + \int_0^1 f^{-1}(y) dx = bd -ac$$
for $f(a) = c$ and $f(b) = d$.

Can we say anything similar about
$$\int_0^1 (f^{-1}(x))^2dx$$
that is, express it somehow as a function of an integral of $f$ only?

Comment: Try the substitution $y=f^{-1}(x)$ and integration by parts on $x^2$ and the rest of the integral